# Notation in sums

Tags: summation, notation

What do those sum notations exactly mean? Are my interpretations correct?
(Do they need more context to make sense?)

$$\sum_{\left<i,j\right>}^{i=3} ij \stackrel?= 1\cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 4 \tag 1$$
$$ \sum_{\{s_i = \pm 1\}}^{i=3} s_i \stackrel?= \underbrace{(+1-1)}_{s_1} + \underbrace{(+1-1)}_{s_2} + \underbrace{(+1-1)}_{s_3} \tag 2 $$

Comment: I recommend you type out your steps rather than sending a picture. Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: @Arbuja: it's way more convenient to take a snapshot than to tex it out on my cellphone. Besides, there are no other steps done than depicted here. I hope this is fine.

Comment: This are physics questions? the first one is some sum over next neighbours on and second one seem to be some spin sum. 
Nevertheless you will need some specification over the limit for $j$ in the first sum, the second seems to be fine

Comment: @t.rathgen This is fine. I am just recommending :).

Comment: @tired: yeah, sums like that appear in statistical mechanics. What I've written, though, has no real physical meaning. I thought those notations are more generally known and I just wanted to make sure I got the (purely mathematically) meaning correct